# Escaping open paren in agent ransack does not work

Tags: windows-search, agent-ransack

I'm trying to search for the text "names(" (without quotes) in a folder of code.  I've tried "names(" but that returns no results where they should be results.  Not sure how to deal with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on options, select Regular Expressions for your search string,

Then use this:

```
string\(
```

`\(` will escape your open paren.